# Angular won't load my service module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-module

I have the following three files for an app using Angular 1.5:

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.service'])
    .controller('AppController', AppController);

AppController.$inject = ['$scope', 'GreeterService'];

function AppController($scope, GreeterService) {
    $scope.greeting = GreeterService.greet("World");
}
```

service.js

```
angular.module('myApp.service', [])
.factory('GreeterService', function() {
    return {
        salutation: 'Hello',
        greet: function(name) {
            return this.salutation + ' ' + name + '!';
        }
    };
});
```

and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

</head>
<body>
    <header>

    </header>

    <main ng-app='myApp'>
        <div ng-controller="AppController">
            {{ greeting }}
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <script src="libs/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="libs/angular-route.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot get the app to load properly, and I don't know why. app.js and service.js are in the same directory. I have made the modules for both, I'm injecting myApp.service in the dependencies for myApp, myApp.service defines a factory that returns an object to use as the singleton, and all of the names match. The error I'm getting in the console tells me myApp.service couldn't be loaded because it isn't available. myApp and myApp.service is using DI correctly, as far as I can tell, and I don't think it's the controller because it's not even getting that far. I really can't see what the problem is and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: did you add link of `service.js` file inside `index.html`

Comment: No, but I have another project where I did the same thing I'm trying to do now where I didn't src the service file and it worked just fine. I did try adding it, and it made the app work, but I don't see why it would need that when the module loader should take care of that.

Comment: nope it will not work if you have some expectation from service.

Comment: Module loader loads only modules and not definitions in other files. For that you would need a module loader which supports import from files, such as webpack

Comment: can you show console error which you are getting?

Comment: I was wrong about the other project. I didn't realize this was necessary because my minifier concatenated the app and service files together without me knowing, so the service file actually was linked in the html, and I didn't know it. Thanks for the help, that really explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not added the reference for `service.js` having the definition of your service in `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
</header>

<main ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        {{ greeting }}
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <script src="libs/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know this was necessary because my build process hid the fact that the service file for the other project was concatenated onto the app file. It was linked in the html because of that, and that's why the other project worked, and this one didn't. Thanks for the help!